# Proof of Difference in Return Between Two Policies

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, proofs, value-functions, bellman-equations

I am attempting to understand why Lemma 6.1 holds in [this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Epabbeel/cs287-fa09/readings/KakadeLangford-icml2002.pdf) on reinforcement learning. I have two questions. First, when defining the value function V(s), why is there a leading (1-γ) term? In the Bellman backup, I understand that it's necessary for normalization. However, in the paper's definition below I don't see the need.

[image]

My second question pertains to the equivalence below. Specifically, I'm not sure how they pulled a V_pi(s) out of the expectation and how there's an extra γ*V_pi(s_t+1) term inside of the expectation.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Split this post into 2, one for each question. thanks.